# Need to 7zip files with specific names

Tags: excel, vba

I am struck with my files which are to be 7zipped with specific names. Can any one help
New file names are in D17 to D23 column, Paths are in B17 to B23 column, Now B column files to 7zipped then renamed as D column

```
Sub RenameFiles()
    
    'Tools -> References -> Microsoft Scripting Runtime
    Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
    Dim fl As File
    Dim i As Long
    Dim strCommand As String
    
    For i = 17 To 22
        ' Set fl = fso.GetFile(Cells(i, "B")) 'Path is taken from column "A"
        ' fl.Name = Cells(i, "D") 'Rename with name taken from column B
        strCommand = "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" & "7z.exe a -r" & " " & Chr(34) & Cells(i, "D").Values & Chr(34) & " " & Chr(34) & Cells(i, "B").Values & "*.txt" & Chr(34)
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

How about *.exe* once only:

```vb
strCommand = "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" & " a -r" & " " & Chr(34) & Cells(i, "D").Values & Chr(34) & " " & Chr(34) & Cells(i, "B").Values & "*.txt" & Chr(34)
```

Comment: nope, not working

Comment: It is only the command line. You also have to execute it to get something "working".